# Alternative Power Supply for Raspberry Pi 5 with 67 watt

Tags: hardware, power, power-supply, pi-5

I don't know why, but my original Raspberry power supply doesn't work anymore.

I found a power supply at home, but it provides 67 watt instead of the original 27 watt. Is this a problem or could using 67 watt cause damage to my Pi 5?

Comment: It doesn't matter on the wattage it matters much more on the VOLTAGE. The voltage cannot exceed 5.25V or your RPi will blow up. It will take whatever current it needs (that's 5A with the official supply).

Comment: To me the question is not specific.  Does the 67 watt power supply have a USB-C output?  That would normally be 5.25V.  However the Pi 5's maximum amperage is listed as 5 amp (I assume that's with dual monitors and all USB ports pulling maximum current).  My headless Pi 5 with no USB devices is using less than 0.6 amps when system is idle.  Running "stress --cpu 4" increases current usage to 1.25 amp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wattage rating is nothing to be concerned about; the RPi (or any electrical device) will only use the power it needs - no more.

The things you should look at more closely are the voltage rating, and (if you can find them) the electrical specs on load regulation. If it's a USB supply/charger from a reputable manufacturer you will probably be OK.